How to write the three-qubit Hamiltonian describing XXX Heisenberg interaction between $B,C$ and $A$ interacting with both $B$ and $C$?
Suppose there are three particles: A, B, and C. Particles B and C are subjected to XXX Heisenberg interaction, while the spin of particle A interacts with both B and C. then we have:
$
H_{BC} = J_x \sigma_B^x \sigma_C^x + J_y \sigma_B^y \sigma_C^y + J_z \sigma_B^z \sigma_C^z
$
$
H_{A-BC} =  \left( \sigma_{A}^{x} \otimes \left( \sigma_{B}^{x} + \sigma_{C}^{x} \right) + \sigma_{A}^{y} \otimes \left( \sigma_{B}^{y} + \sigma_{C}^{y} \right) + \sigma_{A}^{z} \otimes \left( \sigma_{B}^{z} + \sigma_{C}^{z} \right) \right)
$
Then the total hamiltoian is as follows:
$H = H_{BC} + H_{A-BC}
$
Did I write all of the above correctly, or did I make any mistakes?

You have written a valid Hamiltonian. What could make it correct or incorrect? the part "particle A interacts with both B and C" is rather vague. (Often, when somebody talks about the XXX model, all 3 coupling strengths are taken to be the same)

Part A is seprable while part B and C are entangled due to xx interaction

Part A is not separable. It would be if there were just one tensor product. But this is a sum of terms.
